# Stateless functional component vs. additional render method in a stateful component?

Tags: reactjs

As a really basic example, imagine I wanted to render a div containing some text outside of my render() method. Which of these options would be better?

```
class StatefulComponent extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      {this.renderTextDiv(this.state.text)}
    )
  }

  renderTextDiv(text) {
    return <div>text</div>
  }
}
```

or

```
class StatefulComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextDiv text={this.state.text} />
    )
  }
}

function TextDiv({text}) {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
}
```

Or would you completely pull the stateless component into its own class? Or does it just not matter at all? Does one make testing easier? Readability? Any differences at all?

Comment: Okay thats better.

Comment: the first one definitely works @Omar

Answer (score 1):

It does not make any difference in terms of what is being displayed. However, it definitely changes the structure and readability of the code.

For myself, I try to divide the structure into as much Components as possible, and so does [Thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) suggests. However, if you think that the element does not structurally differ from its parent component and thus does not deserve its own separate component but you require some readability and re-usability, the top code works.

Answer (score 1):

The first one looks more concise in my opinion. You could render html in methods if it's not a big code, or, just a conditional rendering inside the component. Whenever you have some html rendering with a big structure and some functionality, it is always good to separate it into its proper component, because you probably would reuse this code later. Again: If it's not a big code or functionality, it's ok to use html rendering inside a method.